# Print PDF first page in Xamarin form UWP Cross-platform(desktop)

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, cross-platform

I am trying to print PDF file in xamarin form UWP (desktop).I have implemented Print functionality using PrintManager (https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/91163/problem-with-printing-webview-in-uwp-phone).
But in above post its passing html code to ViewToPrint.

I have worked with sample HTML/Image passed to ViewToPrint.It is working fine. But I have PDF , I need to convert it into either IMAGE or HTML.

Highly appreciated to resolve my problem.

Comment: You could follow this[blog](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/8767/how-to-print-pdf-documents-in-xamarin-forms-platform). and this [code sample](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/PDFPrintingSample-1198012909).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is this paid package? Im very weak in this to find out paid and free version of package. thanks